# Jquery validation with dynamic error message

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I need to validate a field with multiple conditions with different error messages. How could I fix this?

```
$.validator.addMethod("customMethod", function(value, element) {
    var msg;
    if(cond1){
       msg = "msg1";
    }
    else if(cond2){
       msg = "msg2";
    }
    else if(cond3){
       msg = "msg3";
    }
}, msg);
```

Comment: could you provide with a jsfiddle please?

Comment: I could not pass out the msg as it is undefined at the end.

Comment: Did you try adding breakpoints and checking what is the value, before the 'if' exits?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would have to pass in an anonymous function in the [`message`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) parameter, because you just cannot pass `msg` from the result of the previous anonymous function to the next parameter (as `msg`, in your context, only exists within that particular anonymous function scope).

```
$.validator.addMethod("customMethod", function(value, element) {
    // Do your usual stuff here.
}, function (params, element) {
    var msg;
    if(cond1){
       msg = "msg1";
    }
    else if(cond2){
       msg = "msg2";
    }
    else if(cond3){
       msg = "msg3";
    }
    return msg;
});
```

However, you could just declare `msg` in the global scope like this:

```
var msg;
var dynamicErrorMsg = function () { return msg; }
$.validator.addMethod("customMethod", function(value, element) {
    if(cond1){
       msg = "msg1";
    }
    else if(cond2){
       msg = "msg2";
    }
    else if(cond3){
       msg = "msg3";
    }
}, dynamicErrorMsg);
```

And this would work as well.

Comment: thanks, it works like a charm.

Comment: Works like a charm for the first solution